# D-Link DWA-182 Rev C Ubuntu 23.10 is not working

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb, 23.10

I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu 23.10. I have a D-Link dwa-182 rev c USB wifi adapter. I've tried a few of the methods on here for installing the correct drivers and yet no wifi settings have appeared.

Information for Wifi diagnosis: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/9Z5Pt9xNkk/

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 09 Nov 2023 15:55 AEDT +1100

Booted last: 09 Nov 2023 00:00 AEDT +1100

Script from: 25 Jan 2020 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.10
Release:    23.10
Codename:   mantic

##### kernel ############################

Linux 6.5.0-10-generic #10-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Oct 13 13:49:38 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V [8086:15b8] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V [1458:e000]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e

0d:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1969:e091] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1458:e000]
    Kernel driver in use: alx

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2001:3315 D-Link Corp. DWA-182 Wireless AC Dualband Adapter(rev.C) [Realtek RTL8812AU]
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 062a:410a MosArt Semiconductor Corp. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

##### secure boot #######################

'mokutil' is not installed (package "mokutil").

##### lsmod #############################

8812au               1687552  0
intel_wmi_thunderbolt    16384  0
mxm_wmi                12288  0
cfg80211             1314816  1 8812au
wmi                    40960  3 video,intel_wmi_thunderbolt,mxm_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp13s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp13s0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.0.155/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp13s0
       valid_lft 86271sec preferred_lft 86271sec
    inet6 fe80::<IP6 'enp13s0' [IF1]>/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp0s31f6' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp13s0   no wireless extensions.

enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp13s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.155 metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp13s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp13s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.155 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root         832       1  0 15:53 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp13s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Qualcomm Atheros
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         alx
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 6.5.0-10-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp13s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               3 (limited)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:0d:00.0/net/enp13s0
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:0d:00.0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp13s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     netplan-enp13s0
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       813c7915-6a7d-3b79-ab05-c04ab57cd351
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     1000 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.0.155/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 192.168.0.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.0.1, mt = 100
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.0.255
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp_client_identifier = 01:<MAC 'enp13s0' [IF1]>
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        expiry = 1699591988
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        host_name = dominic-ubuntu
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        ip_address = 192.168.0.155
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       routers = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::<IP6 'enp13s0' [IF1]>/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/1
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   813c7915-6a7d-3b79-ab05-c04ab57cd351 | netplan-enp13s0

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s31f6
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         e1000e
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 6.5.0-10-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               0.8-4
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp0s31f6' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.6/net/enp0s31f6
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:00:1f.6
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com./

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-31-mac-addr-change]
match-device=driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

grep: /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml: Permission denied
grep: /lib/netplan/00-network-manager-all.yaml: Permission denied

##### iw reg get ########################

'iw' is not installed (package "iw").

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp13s0   no frequency information.

enp0s31f6  no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp13s0   Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp0s31f6  Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[8812au]
filename:       /lib/modules/6.5.0-10-generic/updates/dkms/8812au.ko.zst
description:    Realtek Wireless Lan Driver
license:        GPL
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
name:           8812au
vermagic:       6.5.0-9-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           rtw_ips_mode:The default IPS mode (int)
parm:           rtw_usb_rxagg_mode:int
parm:           rtw_qos_opt_enable:int
parm:           ifname:The default name to allocate for first interface (charp)
parm:           if2name:The default name to allocate for second interface (charp)
parm:           rtw_initmac:charp
parm:           rtw_channel_plan:int
parm:           rtw_special_rf_path:int
parm:           rtw_chip_version:int
parm:           rtw_rfintfs:int
parm:           rtw_lbkmode:int
parm:           rtw_network_mode:int
parm:           rtw_channel:int
parm:           rtw_mp_mode:int
parm:           rtw_wmm_enable:int
parm:           rtw_vrtl_carrier_sense:int
parm:           rtw_vcs_type:int
parm:           rtw_busy_thresh:int
parm:           rtw_ht_enable:int
parm:           rtw_bw_mode:int
parm:           rtw_ampdu_enable:int
parm:           rtw_rx_stbc:int
parm:           rtw_ampdu_amsdu:int
parm:           rtw_vht_enable:int
parm:           rtw_lowrate_two_xmit:int
parm:           rtw_rf_config:int
parm:           rtw_power_mgnt:int
parm:           rtw_smart_ps:int
parm:           rtw_low_power:int
parm:           rtw_wifi_spec:int
parm:           rtw_antdiv_cfg:int
parm:           rtw_antdiv_type:int
parm:           rtw_enusbss:int
parm:           rtw_hwpdn_mode:int
parm:           rtw_hwpwrp_detect:int
parm:           rtw_hw_wps_pbc:int
parm:           rtw_max_roaming_times:The max roaming times to try (uint)
parm:           rtw_mc2u_disable:int
parm:           rtw_80211d:Enable 802.11d mechanism (int)
parm:           rtw_notch_filter:0:Disable, 1:Enable, 2:Enable only for P2P (uint)
parm:           rtw_hiq_filter:0:allow all, 1:allow special, 2:deny all (uint)
parm:           rtw_adaptivity_en:0:disable, 1:enable, 2:auto (uint)
parm:           rtw_adaptivity_mode:0:normal, 1:carrier sense (uint)
parm:           rtw_nhm_en:0:disable, 1:enable (uint)
parm:           rtw_amplifier_type_2g:BIT3:2G ext-PA, BIT4:2G ext-LNA (uint)
parm:           rtw_amplifier_type_5g:BIT6:5G ext-PA, BIT7:5G ext-LNA (uint)
parm:           rtw_RFE_type:default init value:64 (uint)
parm:           rtw_TxBBSwing_2G:default init value:0xFF (uint)
parm:           rtw_TxBBSwing_5G:default init value:0xFF (uint)
parm:           rtw_tx_pwr_lmt_enable:0:Disable, 1:Enable, 2: Depend on efuse (int)
parm:           rtw_tx_pwr_by_rate:0:Disable, 1:Enable, 2: Depend on efuse (int)
parm:           rtw_phy_file_path:The path of phy parameter (charp)
parm:           rtw_load_phy_file:PHY File Bit Map (int)
parm:           rtw_decrypt_phy_file:Enable Decrypt PHY File (int)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/6.5.0-10-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko.zst
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       6.5.0-10-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[8812au]
if2name: wlan%d
ifname: wlan%d
rtw_80211d: 0
rtw_adaptivity_en: 0
rtw_adaptivity_mode: 0
rtw_ampdu_amsdu: 0
rtw_ampdu_enable: 1
rtw_amplifier_type_2g: 0
rtw_amplifier_type_5g: 0
rtw_antdiv_cfg: 2
rtw_antdiv_type: 0
rtw_busy_thresh: 40
rtw_bw_mode: 33
rtw_channel: 1
rtw_channel_plan: 89
rtw_chip_version: 0
rtw_decrypt_phy_file: 0
rtw_enusbss: 0
rtw_hiq_filter: 1
rtw_ht_enable: 1
rtw_hwpdn_mode: 2
rtw_hwpwrp_detect: 0
rtw_hw_wps_pbc: 1
rtw_initmac: (null)
rtw_ips_mode: 0
rtw_lbkmode: 0
rtw_load_phy_file: 68
rtw_low_power: 0
rtw_lowrate_two_xmit: 1
rtw_max_roaming_times: 2
rtw_mc2u_disable: 0
rtw_mp_mode: 0
rtw_network_mode: 0
rtw_nhm_en: 0
rtw_notch_filter: 0
rtw_power_mgnt: 0
rtw_qos_opt_enable: 0
rtw_rf_config: 5
rtw_RFE_type: 64
rtw_rfintfs: 2
rtw_rx_stbc: 1
rtw_smart_ps: 2
rtw_special_rf_path: 0
rtw_TxBBSwing_2G: 255
rtw_TxBBSwing_5G: 255
rtw_tx_pwr_by_rate: 0
rtw_tx_pwr_lmt_enable: 0
rtw_usb_rxagg_mode: 2
rtw_vcs_type: 1
rtw_vht_enable: 1
rtw_vrtl_carrier_sense: 2
rtw_wifi_spec: 0
rtw_wmm_enable: 1

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-dkms.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist b44
blacklist bcma
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist ssb

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################
```

Results of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2001:3315 D-Link Corp. DWA-182 Wireless AC Dualband Adapter(rev.C) [Realtek RTL8812AU]
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 062a:410a MosArt Semiconductor Corp. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Results `lsmod | grep 88`:

```
8812au               1687552  0
cfg80211             1314816  1 8812au
snd_seq_dummy          12288  0
snd_hrtimer            12288  1
intel_tcc_cooling      12288  0
ac97_bus               12288  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_codec_generic   122880  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ledtrig_audio          12288  1 snd_hda_codec_generic
amdxcp                 12288  1 amdgpu
irqbypass              12288  1 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul       12288  1
polyval_clmulni        12288  0
polyval_generic        12288  1 polyval_clmulni
drm_ttm_helper         12288  1 amdgpu
mxm_wmi                12288  0
input_leds             12288  0
mac_hid                12288  0
msr                    12288  0
efi_pstore             12288  0
hid_generic            12288  0
crc32_pclmul           12288  0
crc_itu_t              12288  1 firewire_core
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try a different driver, in terminal

```
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au
sudo make dkms_install
```

Reboot

Comment: Perfect! Followed these instructions and this issue is solved! Thank you for your expertise